# rbootstrap home page alignement issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my home page I have different box that look like that :
[image]

I would like my home page to look like that :
[image]

I don't know how to do that and reading through Bootstrap doc did not help...
The 5 boxes are in a container, the first box is col-xs-12, all the other col-xs-6. The high of every box change for every user.

The boxes can be hidden by the user if he wants to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise you to make 2 column containers which will hold the boxes:

```
<div class="row">    // this is your left column
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-xs-6">  // right column
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Or per your comment request I would suggest [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)  and you can find a simple example [here](http://www.bootply.com/qSycV1Ds5r)

Comment: The description of my problem was not specific enough. The boxes can be hidden by the user if he wants to. So if the user hide for example the box 2 and 4, the result will be ugly with the left column empty and the right column full...

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your first box as all 12 columns. Make the other 4 be split into 2 different columns, with boxes 2 and 4 on the left and boxes 3 and 5 on the right. [Here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rND89/).

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 box one"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 two-cols">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-one">
            <div class="col-xs-12 box two"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 box four"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-two">
            <div class="col-xs-12 box three"></div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 box five"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit

You can achieve what you want with javascript. When a box is hidden, you can check if all boxes in the left column are hidden - and if they are - hide the whole column. This will move the right column over into its place. [New demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rND89/1/)

Function to check if left column's boxes are hidden:

```
function hideCol1() {
    var hide = true;
    $('.col-one .box').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).is(':hidden')) {
            hide = false;
        }
    });
    return hide;
}
```

Then use this in your event that hides boxes:

```
if(hideCol1()) {
    $('.col-one').hide();
}
```

Comment: The description of my problem was not specific enough. The boxes can be hidden by the user if he wants to. So if the user hide for example the box 2 and 4, the result will be ugly with the left column empty and the right column full...

Comment: So you would want box 3 to move left and box 5 to move up into 3's place in that scenario?

Comment: Yes exactly ! Every box have to go in the "highest" place possible ! For example if I have box 1 with height 300px and box 2,3,4 with height 100px, the result should be  : box 1 at the left, box 2,3,4 at the right ! I don't know if my example is clear >< It must act like an inverted tetris ^^

Comment: I have updated my answer. Assuming you are okay with a javascript based answer, it seems to work well.